# Which of the items below are worth mentioning in my admission documents?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, cv, statement-of-purpose

I really worried about what should I write in my admission documents, such as resume/CV, statement of purpose, informal email communications with professors. From the list below, please tell me what items have enough academic value to be mentioned in such documents?

Note that its a application in PhD program in computer science for US universities

- Stack Overflow (generally Stack Exchange) reputation and badges
- [Coursera](http://coursera.org/) accomplished courses
- Small-scaled programming projects (absolutely with no academic value)
- Github programming repositories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This list does reflect your technical abilities and not your research-based activities.**

Therefore, all things listed here should be packaged and be presented under a section
(e.g., such as *'Related Technical Activities'*); to represent your technical abilities to program and contribute (e.g., Github).

Comment: It would also be useful to highlight these as evidence that you are able to collaborate, to keep up with the latest trends in technology and software development, and that you have good skills in tutoring (Stack Overflow).